# Detect mouse and keyboard events in iframe with embedded PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe

I am writing some Javascript to detect how long a user spends on a single HTML page. I don't want to count idle time, so I'm using jQuery to detect mouse and keyboard events, so that I can reset the idle timer. I run into a problem when trying to detect activity in an iframe that contains an embedded PDF. You can see an example of the events failing to fire here:

http://jsfiddle.net/89s7q/41/

The JS:

```
var frameSelected = false, i = 0;

var selected = function(e) {
  if (frameSelected !== true)
  {
    frameSelected = true;
    $("#console").prepend((++i) + " Selected<br/>");
  }
};

var deselected = function() {
  if (frameSelected === true)
  {
    frameSelected = false;
    $("#console").prepend((++i) + " Deselected<br/>");
  }
};

$("iframe").mouseout(deselected);
$("iframe").mouseover(selected);
```

Is there a way to get events to fire in the iframe?

Answer (score 3):

You could put a transparent overlay on top of the iframe, so users will still see the iframe content but you can track mouse events on the overlay.

Comment: If I did that, is there a way to redirect the events to the underlying iframe? I still want the user to be able to interact with the PDF in the iframe.